# How to test if a block gets invoked

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, sentestingkit

I have a unit test for a method that should call either a completion block or a failed block. Now I know for every case which one should be called so I use `STFail` in the block that should not be invoked.

How can I now test that the block that should be invoked is really invoked?

This is my setup:

```
NSString *parameter = @"foo";
[controller doSomethingWithParameter:parameter withcompletionBlock: 
^(NSString *result)
{
    // This block should be invoked
    // Check if the result is correct
    STAssertEquals(result, kSomeOKConstant, @"Result shout be 'kSomeOKConstant'");
} failedBlock:
^(NSString *errorMessage) {
    STFail(@"No error should happen with parameter '%@'",parameter);
}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add block variables, and set them from inside your blocks:

```
BOOL __block successBlockInvoked = NO;
BOOL __block failureBlockInvoked = NO;
NSString *parameter = @"foo";
[controller doSomethingWithParameter:parameter withcompletionBlock: 
^(NSString *result) {
     successBlockInvoked = YES;
     STAssertEquals(result, kSomeOKConstant, @"Result shout be 'kSomeOKConstant'");
} failedBlock:
^(NSString *errorMessage) {
    failureBlockInvoked = YES;
    STFail(@"No error should happen with parameter '%@'",parameter);
}];
```

At this point you can make assertions about the values of `successBlockInvoked` and `failureBlockInvoked`: if the expected one is not set, your test has failed.

Comment: But where can I do this assertion. If I do it after the call to `doSomethingWithParameter` then it will be set to `NO` anyway, right?

Comment: @Besi no, once it is set in the block, it will remain set to YES even after doSomethingWithBlock returns. That is the "magic" of __block variables.

Comment: No way?! Now I am both confused and excited :-) I'll give it a shot, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused.If you assert right after doSomething is called your successBlockInvoked boolean will not be set unless the block happened to get called synchronously, which I guess could happen sometimes, but I don't see this as a general solution. You would need to have a while loop waiting for the block to get called and a timeout in case it never does. I think, no?

Comment: @eddy Correct, the code snippet assumes that the block is executed synchronously in the testing environment. It should be OK for quick demos, but obviously one needs to implement *some* waiting mechanism in real-life (i.e. non-testing) environments.

Comment: Is there any way without introducing a boolean?

Comment: @fatuhoku No, it is not possible, because you would not be able to distinguish between a situation when your block successfully passed an assertion and a situation when your block did not assert anything at all, because it has not been invoked.